# Retrieve Amazon CloudWatch Alarms using REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to retrieve all open Alarms (alerts) from Amazon Monitoring tool: Cloudwatch, using REST API GET.

And while Azure Monitor has a very clear [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall) that contains the Alerts Management endpoint:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts?includeContext=True&api-version=2018-05-05

On Amazon side, on the other hand. i got confused.

After reading Amazon Cloudwatch documentation.
I understood that i need to pull the data from Cloudwatch Alarms, and not from Cloudwatch Log or Cloudwatch Events.

But i didn't find a corresponding endpoint to use in order to retrieve all the open Alarms (alerts) in Cloudwatch using REST API Get, from the available AWS Service Points:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Can someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/ruby/example_code/cloudwatch/cw-ruby-example-show-alarms.rb

here is a ruby example of `describe alarms` end point. You should be able to do the same using other programming languages as well.